# PHP Error: mcrypt_encrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize

Tags: php, mcrypt

I get the error **mcrypt_encrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize** on second line.

```
    $data = "Currency=GBP&SuccessURL=test&FailureURL=test&VendorEMail=test&SendEMail=1&eMailMessage=&Amount=&Description=&CustomerName=test test&CustomerEMail=test&BillingSurname=test&BillingFirstnames=test&BillingAddress1=test&BillingAddress2=test&BillingCity=test&BillingPostCode=test&BillingCountry=test&BillingPhone=test&DeliverySurname=test&DeliveryFirstnames=test&DeliveryAddress1=test&DeliveryAddress2=test&DeliveryCity=test&DeliveryPostCode=test&DeliveryCountry=test\u0003\u0003\u0003";
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'test', $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 'test');
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case also it was giving same error. I was using actual password earlier. But when i used encrypted password, it worked. In sagepay.php line 54, protected $encryptPassword="". Here i used encrypted password which i got in my test account. Now its working. 

This might help.

Thanks

Comment: encrypted password means how to encrypt password can you elaborate?

Comment: u need not encrypt password. U will get it with your acc.

Comment: thanx you are right... I got the password. can you please share your email id.

Comment: catchsajal24seven@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

The **IV parameter** is not the 4th parameter of mcrypt_encrypt() as I thought it would be. It is actually the last parameter, the 5th one.
It's specified here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php as **iv**.

The blocksize of the $data was 16 for this instance, so the last parameter in mcrypt_encrypt() needed to be 16 characters long.

The blocksize is the number with which the data string should be divisible, otherwise the last part of it needs to be padded to it becomes divisible by it.